# How to Create Toggleable Button using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I know how to create toggleable checkboxes but I need to create a toggleable filter button. For now I only want to know how to structure the HTML and CSS for it to look like this:

[image]

When location 4 filter is clicked, it should look like Location 1, should I code this as anchor tags, buttons or input[type="checkbox"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I simplified and adapted this from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: block;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

        .container input {
            display: none;
        }
        /* Create a custom checkbox */

        .checkmark {
            height: 25px;
            width: 100px;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        .container:hover input~.checkmark {
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }

        .container input:checked~.checkmark {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                <span class="checkmark">Location 1</span>
              </label>

    <label class="container">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="checkmark">Location 2</span>
              </label>

    <label class="container">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="checkmark">Location 3</span>
              </label>

    <label class="container">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="checkmark">Location 4</span>
              </label></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

[See Css Codes](https://codepen.io/atropat/pen/BapQRWP)

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="switch-checkbox">
    <div class="circle-icon"></div>
    <div class="circle-icon2"></div>

  </span>

</label>
```